# Dynamically loading content (files) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

While attempting to dynamically load content using the jQuery.load() function it appears that if the user clicks the link in the nav more than once to replace the contents of:

```
<div id="REPLACEMENT"></div>
```

All previously loaded content remains, and the new content is added. It seems that the contents of the file I'm loading is not actually "clearing" the contents of the div before adding the new content. I'm assuming this because my $.on("click") scripts are all running multiple times (as many times as the user clicked the nav link). I've attempted to

```
$.remove
$("REPLACEMENT").html("")
$("#REPLACEMENT").empty();
```

to no avail, the issue persists. I have found that if I use alternative click detection methods I have varying results:

```
$(".deleteBtn").click( function() {  // Nothing happens.
$(".deleteBtn").on("click", function() { // Nothing happens.
$(document).on("click",".deleteBtn",function() { // Triggers, but multiple times.
```

I'm really stuck on this! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a copy paste of my replacement code, as well as my onclick code:

```
// Enables the Archive, Reporting, and Error-Reporting links in the navigation.
$(document).on("click", "li#archive, li#reporting, li#error-reporting", function() {
    $("#REPLACEMENT").empty();
    $("#REPLACEMENT").load("modules/"+$(this).attr("id")+".html");
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Delete an archive
//$(".deleteBtn").click( function() { 
//$(".deleteBtn").on("click", function() { 
$(document).on("click",".deleteBtn",function() {
//alert('asdf');
    var Record = $(this).attr('id');
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
        if (result == true) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: APIUrl + 'DeleteArchive/' + Record,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    $("#TR_"+Record).remove();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data){
                    console.log("AJAX "+errorThrown+": - " + textStatus);
                    $("#ERROR_RESPONSE").html(data);
                    $("#ERROR_RESPONSE_GROUP").show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: $("#REPLACEMENT").html(""); Should work. You've made syntax errors in the code posted so maybe you mistyped it in your code?

Comment: doesn't make sense since `load()` replaces exiting inner html with new content. That means you don't even need to use `empty()`. Sounds like something else is wrong like perhaps duplicate content from server

Comment: you're correct about the Syntax issues, I typed it by hand instead of copying it. Sorry about that! I'll also continue looking into code being duplicated by something else I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this code:

```
$(document).on("click",".deleteBtn",function() {
```

and this

```
$(".deleteBtn").click( function() { 
$(".deleteBtn").on("click", function() {
```

is simply because the content is dynamically created after the page is loaded. So you have to use a parent that is not dynamically created `$(document)` works.

Now for the real problem you are having

> Triggers, but multiple times

Try adding this to your click event and see if it fixes it. It is not the ideal solution but might help you.

```
$(document).on("click",".deleteBtn",function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    ....
    ....
    ....
});
```

[UPDATE] You confirmed that the above does not work, try this:

```
$(document).off().on("click",".deleteBtn",function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    ....
    ....
    ....
});
```

AND Try this: the `.one` fires the event only once.

```
$(document).one("click",".deleteBtn",function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    ....
    ....
    ....
});
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that! Same result on your suggestion though. The click event is triggering multiple times.

Comment: $(document).off().on("click",".deleteBtn",function(event) { works, but then breaks navigation. I have to refresh the page to get the other navigation links working again. the $.one suggestion has the same results as my OP.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the issue I was having was due to the fact that HTML is removed from the DOM using $.load() but  are not. After reading over [Michael Kenney's solution](http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/10/11/preventing-javascript-files-from-loading-multiple-times/) I crafted my own. Here's the copy/pasta:

Load this in the scripts.js located in your meta for the "home" page.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// In an effort to clean up the pages as the user navigates around.
var loadedPages = [];
function LoadPage(url) {

    $("#REPLACEMENT").load(url, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
        if ($.inArray(url, loadedPages) == -1) { loadedPages.push(url); }
        // console.log(loadedPages)

        if(statusTxt == "error") { alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText); }
    });

}
```

On each subsequent page, do this **BEFORE** your event handlers (clicks):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($.inArray("modules/error-reporting.html", loadedPages) != -1) {
        console.log("Page already loaded.")
        return false;
    }
});
```